# What could cause timers to flash in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, countdowntimer

I am trying to create a timer for user-generated posts that is displayed on the posts. I am using Firestore to store all of the information about the posts.

The code I have does display the timer but when multiple posts are made by multiple users the timer flashes between the correct time and another count down which is unrelated as far as I can see. Here is what I have:

This is how I create each post.

```
post.setTimer(data.getStringExtra("timerDuration"));
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, setEndDate());
Date endtime = cal.getTime();
post.setTimerEndDate(endtime);
addPhotoInfoToDatabase();
finish();
```

My Adapter for the Fragment:

```
adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder postViewHolder, int position, @NonNull Post post) {
        postViewHolder.setPost(post);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_view_layout, parent, false);
        return new PostViewHolder(view);
    }
};
```

If there is more information you need please let me know. Thank you for any help.

***Edit:***
My app also contains a `ViewPager` and I have noticed that when I swipe away from the problem timer and swipe back the issue is fixed.

***Update:***

```
 void setPost(final Post post) {
        ImageView imageView1 = view.findViewById(R.id.firstImageCardView);
        ImageView imageView2 = view.findViewById(R.id.secondImageCardView);
        ImageView profilePic = view.findViewById(R.id.user_image);
        TextView username = view.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        final TextView timer = view.findViewById(R.id.timer);
        final Button chooseRight = view.findViewById(R.id.choose_right);
        final Button chooseLeft = view.findViewById(R.id.choose_left);
        final Button follow = view.findViewById(R.id.follow);
        String displayName;
        final String userId = currentUser.getUid();
        final String postId = post.getUserId();

        setProfilePicture(post);

        final DocumentReference docRefUsers = db
                .collection("users")
                .document(currentUser.getUid());

        final DocumentReference docRefFollowing = db
                .collection("following")
                .document(currentUser.getUid())
                .collection("UserIsFollowing")
                .document(post.getUserId());

        final DocumentReference docRefPosts = db
                .collection("posts")
                .document(post.getUserId())
                .collection("userPosts")
                .document(post.getDate().toString());


        if (userId.equals(postId)) {
            displayName = "Me";
            chooseLeft.setEnabled(false);
            chooseRight.setEnabled(false);
            follow.setText("");
            follow.setEnabled(false);
        } else if (post.getUsername() == null) {
            displayName = "Anonymous";
        } else {
            displayName = post.getUsername();
        }


        if (post.getProfilePicture() != null) {
            Picasso.get().load(post.getProfilePicture())
                    .transform(new CircleTransformActivity())
                    .fit()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(profilePic);
            username.setText(displayName);
        } else {
            Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.blank_profile_pic)
                    .transform(new CircleTransformActivity())
                    .fit()
                    .into(profilePic);
        }

/***********************************************************/
        if(post.getTimerEndDate() != null) {
            Date date = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

            long currentTime = date.getTime();
            long endTime = post.getTimerEndDate().getTime();
            long timeLeft = endTime - currentTime;

            new CountDownTimer(timeLeft, 1000) {

                @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    timer.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                            (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
                            (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
                            (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60));
                    //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    timer.setText("done!");
                }

            }.start();
        }

        Picasso.get()
                .load(post.getImageUrl_1())
                .fit()
                .transform(new RoundedCornersTransformation(30, 30))
                .into(imageView1);


        Picasso.get()
                .load(post.getImageUrl_2())
                .fit()
                .transform(new RoundedCornersTransformation(30, 30))
                .into(imageView2);

        if (!postId.equals(userId)) {
            docRefFollowing.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                        follow.setText("Following");
                        follow.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        follow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Map<String, Object> following = new HashMap<>();
                following.put("Exists", true);

                docRefFollowing.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            docRefFollowing.set(following);
                            docRefUsers.update("following", FieldValue.increment(1));
                        }
                    }
                });

                db.collection("users")
                        .document(postId)
                        .update("followers", FieldValue.increment(1));


                follow.setText("Following");
            }
        });


        if (!postId.equals(userId)) {
            docRefPosts.collection("voted")
                    .document(currentUser.getUid()).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                        whichVoted = documentSnapshot.get("votedFor").toString();
                    }
                    if (whichVoted != null) {
                        switch (whichVoted) {
                            case ("left"):
                                chooseLeft.setEnabled(false);
                                chooseRight.setEnabled(true);
                                break;
                            case ("right"):
                                chooseRight.setEnabled(false);
                                chooseLeft.setEnabled(true);
                                break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        chooseRight.setEnabled(true);
                        chooseLeft.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        chooseLeft.setText(post.getLeftText());
        chooseRight.setText(post.getRightText());

        chooseLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chooseLeft.setEnabled(false);
                chooseRight.setEnabled(true);
                upLeft(docRefPosts, chooseLeft);
            }
        });

        chooseRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                chooseRight.setEnabled(false);
                chooseLeft.setEnabled(true);
                upRight(docRefPosts, chooseRight);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: "flashes between different times" is quite hard to get the point. Emphasize.

Comment: Clarified. Is that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should be aware that RecyclerView re-uses its viewholders each time you scroll past the last visible item on the screen.

> Based on your implementation for every time a user scroll past the
> last visible item or post on the screen, because it is inside a
> RecyclerView the original first-item on the list and even other items
> being scrolled past are recycled and the next item becomes the new
> first-item but being populated with a different post-values as
> expected.
>
> But remember your code instantiates a new CountdownTimer for
> every new post added to the list (where 50 posts equals 50
> Countdowntimers and 50 posts does not necessarily mean 50 views because
> some of the views would probably be recycled by the RecyclerView; you get the logic), hence it allows the
> possibility for multiple CountdownTimer accessing same view which
> causes the flash and will surely lead to a memory leak causing an
> OutOfMemoryError when the user keeps scrolling continuously on a long
> list.

**Recommended Implementation**

Create your CountDownTimer inside your ViewHolder Class

```
public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
    CountDownTimer countdowntimer;

    public FeedViewHolder(View itemView) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Access the timer inside setPost method

```
   void setPost(final Post post) { 

          ...

        long currentTime = date.getTime();
        long endTime = post.getTimerEndDate().getTime();
        long timeLeft = endTime - currentTime;

        if (countdowntimer != null) {
           //there is an existing timer so we cancel it to prevent duplicates
           countdowntimer.cancel();
           }
        countdowntimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeft, 1000) {

            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                timer.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                        (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
                        (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
                        (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60));
                //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                timer.setText("done!");
            }

        }.start();

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you are creating a new timer when your items in the `RecyclerView` is getting recycled after scrolling. The `timeLeft` variable also changes each time you scroll the item and that initializes a new `Timer` which is the reason for the flashing I guess.

Hence I would like to recommend having an array in your adapter. This is for holding all of your `CountDownTimer`s. In the constructor of your adapter, initialize that properly to have the correct values. Let us take a sample implementation like the following.

Declare two arrays like the following.

```
CountDownTimer[] timers = new CountDownTimer[data.size()];
```

Now in the constructor of your adapter do something like the following.

```
// Let us assume the list of Data is dataItems which is being passed to your adapter.
// Your constructor might take other parameters
public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Data> dataItems) {

    for(int i = 0; i < dataItems.size(); i++) {
        long timeLeft = getTimeLeftValue(dataItems.get(i));
        timers[i] = new CountDownTimer(timeLeft, 1000) {
                @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    timer.setText(String.format("%d:%d:%d",
                            (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
                            (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
                            (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60));
                    //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    timer.setText("done!");
                }
            }.start();
    }
}

private long getTimeLeftValue(Data post) {
    Date date = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    long currentTime = date.getTime();
    long endTime = post.getTimerEndDate().getTime();
    timeLeft = endTime - currentTime;

    return timeLeft.
}
```

Now in your `onBindViewHolder` you need to set the timer as follows.

```
timerInstance = timers.get(position);
```

I am assuming that each of your items in the `RecyclerView` is having a timer instance which is showing the `CountDownTimer`.

Comment: So I currently have the timer in a ```ViewHolder```, but from your answer I would be moving it to the adapter for the ```RecyclerView``` is that correct?

Comment: The `ViewHolder` should have the timer instance as well. Otherwise, from the adapter, you cannot actually set the timer to a timer instance in your `ViewHodler`. Yes, you are right, you need to move the implementation of the timer in your adapter.

Comment: It does not appear to be scrolling that triggers behavior. Even when there is just one post it is now doing it.

Comment: It should not. The idea is not creating a new timer instance each time you are assigning one. However, looking more into your code might help more. Please post some of your relevant code in your question.

Comment: I added the adapter with the `onBindViewHolder` I am not sure if there is any other code related to this problem.

Comment: Please post your `setPost` function as well.

Comment: `setPost` added.

Comment: I do not see where you have set the value of your `timer` where the `CountDownTimer` should take the effect.

Comment: Looks like you just have only one Post, in that case, you do not actually need to have a `RecyclerView` to show that.

Comment: No, users can add any number of posts

Comment: Then try to get all the posts first and then create the array of `CountDownTimer`s like I have suggested and then just point to the reference of the timer in your `setPost` function like I suggested. Which will prevent creating new timer instances each time the `setPost` function is called from the adapter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197125/discussion-between-bjorn-and-reaz-murshed).

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify where exactly your logic is in your adapter.

The logic should be within `onBindViewHolder(…)`. You can access the widgets using `viewHolder.findViewById(...)`

Also, `CountDownTimer` is its own thread, and editing a `TextView` or any widget can cause an exception. Wrap the `timer.setText(…)` call within `runOnUiThread()`

Comment: The ```PostViewHolder``` runs in a fragment which contains the ```onBindViewHolder```. I did not include the full ```PostViewHolder``` since a lot of the code in it is unrelated.

Comment: Also when I try to wrap the ```timer.setText(…)``` call within ```runOnUiThread()``` I get a cannot resolve symbol error